# Putting something on your system path

Tags: python, django, linux, ubuntu

I am trying a python, django tutorial. It says type django-admin.py however I get 'command not found' with this.

Someone told me that the problem could be that django is not in your system path, what does that mean?

I am using ubuntu.

Comment: What's your OS? The method is different according to the OS :)

Answer (score 1):

System path is an system environment variable that contains the path for some folders where the os will search for applications, scripts, etc.

In windows `django-admin.py` is in `C:\Python\scripts`, so if you have set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable and added all the required python folder in that variable like `C:\Python;C:\Python\Lib;C:\Python\scripts;C:\Python\Lib\site-packages`, the os will automatically find `django-admin.py` when you will type the command `django-admin.py startproject myproj` on commandline.

same with linux, the `django-admin.py` is in `/usr/bin/django-admin.py` if you install django for the default python installation.
so, one way could be if you create a alias for that script so that you can run it from where ever you want.

i am using centos and what i did is i edited the `/etc/bashrc` and added 
`alias djangoadmin='/usr/bin/django-admin.py'` and it works for me very well.

Answer (score 0):

- On Linux, check this official doc page: [Link](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/InstallationPitfalls)
- On Windows, this one should do want you want: [Link](http://yuji.wordpress.com/2009/08/31/django-on-windows-setting-path-environment-variable/)

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Django from the Ubuntu repositories via `apt-get` or synaptic, the script will be simply `django-admin` (without the `.py`).